# Just need some guidance on dynamically draggable input element on canvas

Tags: html, dynamic, canvas, input, draggable

Okay,so what i trying here is this-

1. I have a canvas.
2. That canvas is contained in a canvas div container.
   3.Before that div i want to be able to add dynamically draggable input elements.
3. The dynamically addable input elements should be draggable just over the canvas.
   5.These dynamically addable inputs will be added through a button.
4. These boxes are supposed to be connected to a particular root input element or something like that.

I dont want you to write me the whole code or anything. Just need a way to go.How can i pull something like this off. 
I need to do this on html5 and i'm a little familiar to jquery,etc. 
Help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you just need to read about how [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) works.

The canvas will just be your target, so it will not be draggable. But it will have to handle the `drop` and `dragend` events. The other elements will need to be draggable.

There are a lot of articles on [adding input elements dynamically.](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/)

Comment: I'm having problem in using the draggable function on the dynamically created input elements? Any views on that?